# VC++ C2011 redefinition errors - unused header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am working with a large console application. The solution contains 5 projects.
I am adding a 6th project to replace one of the existing projects to allow for the use of a GUI.

I am getting many compiler C2011 errors regarding type redefinition. In particular, they are `'struct' type redefinitions` or `'[function]: redefinition; different linkage`. They come from the header files `ws2def.h` and `winsock2.h`.

I've been searching the entire project and the entire solution for where these are included, but I don't see any `#include <ws2def.h>` or `#include <winsock2.h>` statements, nor anything to indicate they are used.

However, there are `External Dependencies` folders/filters included in both the project I'm replacing, and my new project. Both `ws2def.h` and `WinSock2.h` exist in those filters. I wouldn't think that having the same file included in separate projects under one solution would cause these issues. Also, I'm getting these errors when building just my new project, meaning it shouldn't see the old project anyway.

Based on the information I've given, are you able to see where my problem may lie? Is it the case that these header files **must** be `#included` somewhere within the project and I'm just not seeing it? I've considered deleting both the header files from the `External Dependencies` filter because it seems I don't need them. Is there a different, common header file that also includes these header files so that they wouldn't show up in a `CTRL-Find`?

Thank you.

Comment: winsock2.h is unusual, it must be #included *before* windows.h

Comment: I `#include <Windows.h>` in my main .cpp file and have tried to `#include <WinSock2.h>` just above that statement, but it didn't fix anything.

Comment: In that case please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The problem is likely because ``#include <windows.h>`` pulls in the original ``winsock.h`` stuff which isn't compatible with ``winsock2.h``. The usual solution is to use ``#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`` before the ``#include <windows.h>`` and then manually include ``winsock2.h`` after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to have mostly been based on the horrible file structure of the original large project.
Trying to create a new project within the solution to replicate another project as a GUI instead of Console project meant that the compilation of the project was doubling up on many files.

I found another post (can't find it right now) that stated that when a Visual Studio solution compiles, all of the project files are combined, much like all the `#include` statements in a `.c/.cpp/.h` file really just copy all of those files into the file which `#included` them.

My solution was to create a copy of the large project (for backup purposes), and in the copied project, remove the original Console project and only include the UI Project. Files are not longer doubling up because they don't exist in both projects anymore, just the one still existing in the solution.